# Flutter SharedPreferences save in Firebase FCM background and load by button doesn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences

I wanna save value to SharedPreferences when FCM receive message in background (testing on Android emulator):

```dart
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  if (await prefs.setString("test", "test")) {
    debugPrint("Success");
  } else {
    debugPrint("Error");
  }
  debugPrint("Keys: ${prefs.getKeys().toString()}");
}

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
```

```dart
Future<void> _printKeys() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    debugPrint("BUTTON Keys: ${prefs.getKeys().toString()}");
  });
}
```

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async => await _printKeys(),
  child: const Text("get SP keys"))
```

When App in background, message is received, then I put App to foreground and press "get SP keys" button. Edit: The key is not present.
Log:

```
Success               <== FCM BG
Keys: {oldVal, test}  <== FCM BG
BUTTON Keys: {oldVal} <== Button
```

```dart
shared_preferences 2.0.15
shared_preferences_android 2.0.14
shared_preferences_ios 2.1.1
shared_preferences_linux 2.1.2
shared_preferences_macos 2.0.5
shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.1.0
shared_preferences_web 2.0.4
shared_preferences_windows 2.1.2
```

When App is restarted, "test" key is available in SharedPreferences.

What's wrong and how can App get consistent values from SharedPreferences?

Comment: I didn't get your issue, you want to save `test` when you receive a fcm message, and now you are saving it, what is the problem so?

Comment: It's saved but not consistent - after save in FCM BG I wan't to load it in GUI and simply saved key isn't there, so can't be loaded.

Comment: I think you are reset the value some place in your code, search for `prefs.setString` in other part of your code and check that.

Comment: I suppose it's not the case. `test` is normally present after reloading App.

Comment: which fcm version did you use?
i tried on my side. everything work fine. i got all the keys include from the background.

Comment: `firebase_messaging 14.2.1`

Comment: I'm just wondering. Tried another clean virtual Android device no change at all. Did You resumed App? When I close and reopen App it works but when App is just resumed it still doesn't see item saved in FCM BG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK finally figured solution out. It seem SharedPreferences is out of sync in described case.
What I did was adding `prefs.reload()` in between and it worked :-)

```dart
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => {
  prefs.reload().then((_) {
    // Do the staff
  })
});
```

Strange since App should have only one instance of SP.

Comment: It works so as background handler works in isolate (another thread in simple words and data here can be not synced). Considering this solution you shared works ok as we sync data here.